# Alguien sabe como puedo resolver esto

Tags: javascript, nodejs

La funcion recibe un objeto "persona".
// de la forma:
// {
//  nombre: 'Lionel
//  apellido: 'Messi',
//  invitado: true
//  }
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y, además, tiene las propiedades "nombre" y "apellido", tomar esos valores y retorna:
// "Lionel Messi, un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido".
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "apellido", retornar:
// "Bienvenido Sr. Messi".
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "nombre", retornar:
// "Hola Lionel, tu mesa está lista".
// En caso de que no tenga la propiedad "invitado" retornar:
// "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta".

```
// Micódigo hasta este momento:

    const cliente = {
    nombre: "nombre",
    apellido: "apellido",
    invitado: true,
    saludo1: function() {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido + " un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido";
        },
    saludo2: function(){
        return "Bienvenido Sr." + this.apellido;
        },
    saludo3: function(){
        return "Hola " + this.nombre + ", tu mesa está lista";
        },
    sinSaludo: function(){
       return "Disculpe Señor, no está invitado a la fiesta";
        }
  
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a stack overflow, te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que el título resuma el problema específico, así como el cuerpo de la pregunta sea más entendible

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo resuleves con condicionales. En lugar de 4 métodos usa uno solo: saludo que devolverá el valor adecuado según el contenido del objeto. Doy por supuesto que los datos de nombre y apellido serán strings vacios si no se asigna algún valor.
Uso trim por si nombre o apellido son cadenas de espacios. Considero que no tener la propiedad invitado significa invitado:false. Y no tener nombre o apellidos significa que son cadenas vacías.

```js
const cliente = {
    nombre: "",
    apellido: "",
    invitado: true,
    saludo: function() {
    saludo='';
    //comprobamos que hay nombre y/o apellido
    if( this.nombre.trim()+this.apellido.trim()!='')
      {
      //comprobamos que está invitado
      if(this.invitado){
          if(this.nombre.trim() !='' && this.apellido.trim() !='')
              saludo = this.nombre + " " + this.apellido + " un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido";
          else if (this.nombre.trim() =='' &&  this.apellido.trim() !='')
              saludo= "Bienvenido Sr." + this.apellido;    
          else if (this.nombre.trim() !='' &&  this.apellido.trim() =='')
              saludo = "Hola " + this.nombre + ", tu mesa está lista";
      }
    else { 
          saludo= "Disculpe Señor, no está invitado a la fiesta";
        }
      }   
   return saludo;     
   }
}
console.log(cliente.saludo())
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma en la que escribí esta en JS ES6, podrías buscar información sobre todo eso ya que te ayuda mucho a como escribir tu código.

Para obtener la solución a tu problema se hace mediante condicionales, preguntando una y otra vez si cumple ciertos requisitos para entrar o no, y así generar una respuesta.

La destructuración se utiliza para obtener de manera mas efectiva los atributos de un objeto, y no estar escribiendo `objeto.atributo`

En tu enunciado indicaste que tienes que crear una funcion que reciba un objeto por lo tanto el objeto y la funcion deben estar separados, y el objeto lo puedes destructurar en la misma linea que lo recibe: `saludo = (cliente) => { ...` o `saludo = ({ nombre, apellido, invitado }) => { ...`

```
const nuevoCliente = {
  nombre: '',
  apellido: '',
  invitado: true,
}


const saludo = (cliente) => { // Funcion flecha
  const { nombre, apellido, invitado } = cliente; // Destructuracion

  let respuesta = '';
  
  if (invitado) {
    if (nombre && apellido) {
      respuesta = `${nombre} ${apellido} un gusto tenerlo nuevamente`
    } else if (nombre) {
        respuesta = `Hola ${nombre} tu mesa esta lista`
    } else if (apellido) {
      respuesta = `Bienvenid@  Sr/a ${apellido}`
    } else {
      respuesta = `El empleado debe tener un nombre o un apellido`
    }
  } else {
    respuesta = 'Usted no esta invitado';
  }

  return respuesta;
}

saludo(nuevoCliente)
```

Te aconsejo encarecidamente que busques información sobre las nuevas formas de escribir código en JavaScript, eso te ayudara bastante.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Gracias, definitivamente ayuda, y seguiré tu consejo, precisamente estoy en proceso de aprendizaje y tu consejo me será de utilidad.