# Como puedo resolver este problema

Tags: javascript

tengo que realizar este ejercicio:

```
    // La funcion recibe un objeto "persona".
      // de la forma: 
      // {
      //  nombre: 'Lionel
      //  apellido: 'Messi',
      //  invitado: true
      //  }
      // Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y, además, tiene las propiedades "nombre" y "apellido", tomar esos valores y retorna:
      // "Lionel Messi, un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido".
      // Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "apellido", retornar:
      // "Bienvenido Sr. Messi".
      // Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "nombre", retornar:
      // "Hola Lionel, tu mesa está lista".
      // En caso de que no tenga la propiedad "invitado" retornar:
      // "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta"
```

Esto es lo que se me ocurrio:

```
        function bienvenidoSr(persona) {  
          
        for(let clave in persona)
            if(clave["nombre"] != undefined && clave["apellido"] != undefined && clave["invitado"] == true) {
              return clave["nombre"] + " " + clave["apellido"] + " un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvendo";
            }
            if(clave["apellido"] != undefined && clave["invitado"] == true) {
              return "Bienvenido Sr. " + clave["apellido"];
            }
            if(clave["nombre"] != undefined && clave["invitado"] == true) {
              return "Hola," + clave["nombre"] + "tu mesa esta lista";
            }
            if(clave["invitado"] !=true) {
              return "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta";
            }
            
            } 
          }
```

Cabe aclarar que el ultimo IF me salta como que esta correcto, pero los tres anteriores no. Ya estoy hacia varias horas con este ejercicio. No estoy seguro si estoy colocando mal los operadores o los 3 primeros if.

Comment: porque recorrer el objeto con un for , si tu funcion dice que recibe UN (1) objeto?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Alguien sabe como puedo resolver esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/467776/alguien-sabe-como-puedo-resolver-esto)

Answer (score 0):

no se porque estas usando un for para iterar el objeto, si en el enunciado dice que tu funcion recibe **un (1) objeto**, hay varias formas de hacer lo que te solicita el enunciado, yo lo haria de la siguiente forma:

```js
let messiInvitado = {nombre:"leonel", apellido:"messi", invitado:true}
let messiNoInvitado = {nombre:"leonel", apellido:"messi", invitado:false}
let messiSinNombre = {apellido:"messi", invitado:true}
let messiSinApellido = {nombre:"leonel", invitado:true}
function bienvenidoSr(Persona){
  //Aca validamos si esta invitado o no 
  if(!Persona.invitado){
    //No esta invitado retorna el mensaje y se termina la ejecucion
    return "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta"
  }
  //De aqui para abajo no es necesario validar invitado=true
  
  //Si tiene nombre y apellido
  if(Persona.nombre!=undefined && Persona.apellido!=undefined)
    return `${Persona.nombre} ${Persona.apellido}, un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido`
    //Si tiene solo nombre
  if(Persona.nombre!=undefined)
    return `Hola ${Persona.nombre}, tu mesa esta lista`
    //Si tiene solo apellido
  if(Persona.apellido!=undefined)
    return `Bienvenido sr ${Persona.apellido}`
}
console.log(bienvenidoSr(messiInvitado))
console.log(bienvenidoSr(messiNoInvitado))
console.log(bienvenidoSr(messiSinNombre))
console.log(bienvenidoSr(messiSinApellido))
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No sabia que no era necesario el for. De todas formas probe tu codigo y me siguen apareciendo los mismos errores, que serian estos:

Comment: × debería retornar un saludo apropiado cuando tiene todas las propiedades 
    × debería retornar un saludo apropiado cuando tiene apellido y está invitado
    × debería retornar un saludo apropiado cuando tiene nombre y está invitado

Comment: Se lo que tiene que hacer.. lo lei en el enunciado, el ejercicio que subi cumple con lo descrito en el enunciado, para probar que fuese asi cree varios objetos distintos como puedes ver para cada caso de uso, te invito a oprimas el boton ejecutar del snippet y te fijes en la salida.

Comment: si hay algun error, sube el objeto aca para probar la funcion con el objeto que te da el "error" o la salida incorrecta.

Comment: Ya pude! Gracias!!

Comment: Si te sirvio mi respuesta puedes aceptarla, para dar como cerrada tu pregunta, saludos